# Does `@` in a tag have a special meaning?

Tags: org-mode, org-tags

I see that the only allowed characters in tags are letters, numbers, `_`, and `@`. While `_` apparently serves to visually separate words, why is `@` included? Does it have any special meaning, or a typical use case?

Comment: Many advanced GTD users designate contexts with the @ symbol.  I found a blog about it relating to `org-mode`, but I didn't find a reference in the manual using a cursory Google search.

Comment: Here is a link to an answer I previously wrote for someone who wanted to highlight contexts differently, and I liked it so much, that I use it now myself:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/40918994/2112489

Comment: Thanks! To sum it up, there's no special meaning, but it's just practical (emails, locations, etc use it) so it was added. (Too bad `-` was not.)